# Problem with creating action for an existing button

Tags: popup, action, odoo

I am working with odoo12. 
I created a popup in the purchase.order view so that when the user clicks on the "confirm" button a popup appears asking him to enter a value. when executing, I don't have the popup displayed. I think i have to overwrite the "confirm" button and recreate it beacause i tried to create a new button and it works. Can you tell me about the syntaxe of overwriting an exist button in order to add an action.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <!--Proforma Button-->
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="proforma_button_view">
            <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
            <field name="name">purchase.order.form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//header" position="inside">
                    <button name="button_confirm" string="confirm" type="action" position="inside" class="oe_highlight">
                    </button>
                </xpath>

                <xpath expr="//field[@name='state']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="statusbar_visible">draft,sent,purchase,proforma</attribute>
                </xpath>
            </field>
         </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: That's like extending a view, just change the `name` attribute of the button to the new method name you want to use there.

Comment: Hi, here is my xml file, can you tell me where I must to change exactly :

Comment: Did you override the original method of `purchase.order` like in one of your other questions about `sale.order` or did you write your own method for it?

Comment: I think he need to change the type attribute if they have the same name

Comment: I will add an action to the confirm button of purchase order, I have to keep the confirm action and add the popup action

Comment: I had created my own method:                                                                              def button_confirm(self):
    for order in self:
      view_id=self.env['popup.proforma.invoice']
      new = view_id.create(params[0])
      return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': 'Proforma Receive',
        'res_model': 'popup.proforma.invoice',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_id'    : new.id,
        'view_id': self.env.ref('popup.proforma.invoice',False).id,
        'target': 'new',
      }